# $.each statement stops when it gets to "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When working with Google Maps V3 markers, I make sure to store the name of each marker in an array so I can quickly remove all of them from the map at once. For some reason though, when I call my function that is supposed to iterate through the entire array, removing all markers a long the way, the function returns undefined after only removing a few of the markers.

The array (markersArray) before the function:

```
["markerZip02111", "markerZip02139", "markerZip01002", "markerZip94602", "markerZip02460"]
```

The function code:

```
function removeAllMarkers(exceptId) {
    $.each(markersArray, function(index, value) {
        if(value != exceptId) {
            eval(value+".setMap(null);");
            markersArray.splice(value, 1);
            console.log(value);
        }
    });
}
```

What the console displays:

```
markerZip02111
markerZip01002
markerZip02460
undefined
```

The array after the function is run:

```
["markerZip94602", "markerZip02460"]
```

Clearly the array is running successfully until it hits the "undefined" value and then it stops. What can I do to get around this problem??

Comment: You could easily avoid `eval()` if you set each `markerZipxxxxx` item in an object instead of making them variables. If they're globals, then you can do `window[value] && window[value].setMap(null);`

Comment: It seems unwise to `splice` an array while you are iterating through it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: am not i am: They are globals and I'm not sure what you mean by window[value].

Comment: @Colin, in the context of a browser, `window` is global.

Comment: @hyperslug, so how do you use window instead of eval()?

Comment: @Colin: You use the code in my comment. Global variables are accessible as properties on the global (window) object. So if `value` is `"markerZip02460"`, then `window[value]` is the same as doing `window.markerZip02460`, which is the same as accessing the global `markerZip02460` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting an undefined value during iteration when your starting array doesn't have any undefined values in it is that you're removing items from the array while iterating through it. I guess this confuses the jQuery `$.each()` iterator.

If you look at your output, what is happening is this:

```
1st Iteration
    index === 0, array is["markerZip02111", "markerZip02139", "markerZip01002",
                          "markerZip94602", "markerZip02460"]
    item 0 "markerZip02111" gets removed, shifting all the later elements up
2nd Iteration
    index === 1, but now array is ["markerZip02139", "markerZip01002",
                                   "markerZip94602", "markerZip02460"]
    item 1 "markerZip01002" gets removed, shifting all the later elements up
3rd Iteration
    index ===2, but now array is ["markerZip01002", "markerZip94602",
                                  "markerZip02460"]
    so the last item "markerZip02460" gets removed
4th Iteration
    index === 3, but now array only has two elements so value
    at that index is undefined.
```

Notice that two of the items never got evaluated: the iterator skipped over them because you changed their indexes by removing items.

If you must remove items as you go it is easy with a conventional for loop that iterates backwards such that removing items won't screw up the loop counter. (Or you can use a conventional for loop to go forwards as long as you adjust the counter variable each time you remove an item.)

Also, when you do splice you need to pass the index of the item as the first parameter, not the value of the item. So `markersArray.splice(index, 1);` *not* `markersArray.splice(value, 1);`.

So, something like:

```
function removeAllMarkers(exceptId) {
   var value;
   for (var i = markersArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      value = markersArray[i];
      if (value != exceptId) {
         markersArray.splice(i, 1);
         eval(value+".setMap(null);");
         console.log(value + " removed");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very well written explanation. I completely understand what was going wrong now! Thank you! I'm having a problem with Google Maps not removing markers now, but it has nothing to do with the loop stopping.

Answer (score 2):

I think dotnetstep nailed it, but you can also try wrapping the logic inside the `$.each` with a try/catch for broader handling:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that no error is being passed to catch. The problem is just that the loop stops when "undefined" is passed.

Comment: @Colin- A try/catch loop prevents the program from stopping when it encounters an error (unless you specifically tell it to stop in the "catch" portion). ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $.each(markersArray, function (index, value) {            
             if (value != null && value != undefined  && value!= exceptId) {
                 eval(value + ".setMap(null);");
                 markersArray.splice(value, 1);
                 console.log(value);
             }
         });
```

Comment: When I add the value != undefined, the loop still stops when it gets to the undefined value.